# Google Cloud redirect URI missmatch

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-cloud-console, redirect-uri-mismatch

[image]

I'm getting an error while generating Access Token for my google cloud account. It says redirect URI is miss-match.
I have generated the Client ID and API key, but in scope I've left that parameter blank.

Please guide how to fix this error.

I have added the same URl in Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs.

but it's not working. Please provide a full solution over this.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect uri is used by the authorization server to identify where it is allowed to return the authorization code to.

They are configured in your project on google cloud console under your web application credentials.

[image]

If you click on the link "error details" in the image you have shown it will tell you exactly what redirect uri your application is sending from and what you need to add in the console configuration for your app.

- [Google OAuth2: How the fix redirect_uri_mismatch error. Part 2 server sided web applications.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ)
- [Google Oauth: error redirect_uri_mismatch the javascript origin Quick Fix.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V0-4LnHwFho&)